# Facebook share button large size

Tags: html, facebook

Using the facebook recommendations for creating a share button (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button), I'm actually able to display a simple button.

In the doc, there is a simple attribute (`data-size`) that can be used to customize the size of the button however it doesn't seem to have any effect when set to `large`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your Website Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

        <!-- Your share button code -->
        <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="false">
            <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">
                Share
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that this code is only a copy/paste from the facebook doc and it even works with the "share button configurator" showing a larger button, so is this option deprecated?

By the way, I know there are plenty of solution to work around the css of the button and I'd like to stay away from this as much as possible.

**EDIT:** Seems to work only when logged in to Facebook

Comment: The provided code is working fine with `data-size` set to `large`.

Comment: Not on my side, are you logged in at the same time?

Comment: Interesting. You are right, in Chrome incognito mode the button is smaller, also the configurator is not even providing the option of `size`. I guess facebook is rolling out this option step by step. So you have to stick with the CSS modification or have to wait till the roll out is completed.

Comment: yes you may be right, and the configurator provides the option almost randomly depending on whether you click the "Share Button" link on the left side bar...